# can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (image blend without library)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, blend

this is an assignment on my class, so i need to blend to images together with python using interpolation but i am missing something, perhaps you can help me understand what.

Heres my code so far:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
image_one=Image.open('6.jpg')
image_two=Image.open('14.jpg')

out=Image.new(image_one.mode, image_two.size)

(l,h)=image_one.size
for j in range(0, h):
      for i in range(0, l):
             out.putpixel((i,j), (image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) + image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 ))

out.save("test.jpg","JPEG")
out.show()
```

0.3 is the alpha i want for the blending the two original images are sime size and mode

and i get error
[this is the screenshot the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCPI.png)

Answer (score 1):

At this case you can't multiply float by integer. Convert the latter into float

float(0.3)

in       `out.putpixel((i,j), (image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) + image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * 0.3 ))`

Comment: how to convert 0.3? can you show the success code and explain about the solve? thank you

Comment: try this out :      
out.putpixel((i,j), (image_one.getpixel((i,j)) * (1.0 - 0.3) + image_two.getpixel((i,j)) * float(0.3) ))

Comment: well i see that's first and second variables are not float type then

Answer (score 0):

If the image has multiple color channels (as JPEGs typically do), PIL's [`Image.getpixel` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel) returns the pixel as a tuple. The problem is that tuples can't directly multiply with floats.

The fix is to iterate over the channels with something like

```
[pixel1[c] * (1.0 - 0.3) + pixel2[c] * 0.3 for c in range(3)]
```

Or use the numpy library to vectorize the operation like

```
np.array(pixel1) * (1.0 - 0.3) + np.array(pixel2) * 0.3
```